# How to connect via scp without password using a shell?

Tags: shell, sh, scp

The purpose is to send file from A to B just by putting the password in a shell script. in the long run i would like to do automaticly send file from A to B every 30 minutes.

[image: Code for entering the password by default and error : connect to host 0.0.0.192 port 22: No route to host]

I would prefer to avoid to act on firewall issues and simply put the password in the shell script

Comment: Code and errors  should be added **as text**, not screenshots.

Comment: See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)

Comment: ...that said, the problem you're demonstrating is caused by a typo -- `192:168` instead of `192.168` -- completely unrelated to how your password is being passed around.